# How to delete all particular nodes from XML document in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, foreach

I need to delete all specific nodes from XML file in C#.
In order to do this I selected all nodes with Xpath query and tried the following code:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("//Test");  
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)  
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

QA showed that there are still `<Test>` nodes present in XML file after execution of the code above.

What I do incorrect? How should I delete all specified nodes from XML document?

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted above illustrates the common error of many engineers. I found this code with `foreach` in a serious enterprise back-end.

We should remember that:

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get
>   the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove
>   items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.
>   If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a
>   for loop.
>   [Read more about foreach on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

So the right version of this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)  
{
    nodeList[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeList[i]);
}
```

Comment: The warning applies to changing the collection being iterated, which the `foreach` loop in your question never does.  It appears that you may have misunderstood the actual reason for your problem.  Perhaps you've failed to save the updated XML back to a file?  (Calling `RemoveChild` alone doesn't persist the change to disk.)

Comment: @kjhughes why are you sure that `RemoveChild` does not alter the collection? Why the same code worked correctly with `for` ?

Comment: `node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)` removes `node` from its parent; it has no notion of `node` being among the results of your XPath query.

Comment: @kjhughes visually yes. But logically we do change the `nodelist`.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.  Moving on.  Good luck.